# Android onClick jump to current location and activate LocationListener

Tags: java, android, gps, onclick, locationlistener

*This was created with guidance from Kaj (below)*

Figured my problem out, but this may be useful for someone else looking to jump to current users location:

```
boolean touched = false;

if(touched == false){
    mapController.animateTo(point);
}

myLocationBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        touched = false;
    }
});

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView) 
    {   
//---when user lifts his finger---
if (event.getAction() == 1) {
    touched = true;
     }
return false;
}
```

Comment: How do you stop the locationListener, maybe you are not restarting it caorrectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `onClick` should say `touched = "no";` and not `String touched = "no";`. Btw, it's probably better to change it to a boolean, so that you have `true/false`, instead of having strings. 
You should normally not compare strings with `==`, use `string.equals(anotherString)` instead.